# What does the command \ifCLASSINFOpdf mean?

Tags: macros, pdftex, ieeetran

I found this section in my journal template:

```
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
  % \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\else
  % or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx
  % will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no
  % driver is specified.
  % \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../eps/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi
```

I would like to know what is the meaning of the `\ifCLASSINFOpdf` macro.

I tried googling, but I found no satisfactory answer. I tried searching my The **Not So Short Introduction to LATEX 2ε** to no avail.

Does it detect if I am using **pdfLaTeX** or **LaTeX** or does it do something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is defined in `IEEEtran.cls` (see http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/) and set to true of a PDF flow is used: the class file checks whether `\pdfoutput` is (which seems to be the case in `pdflatex` as the comments suggest there):

```
{\@ifundefined{pdfoutput}{\AtBeginDvi{\special{papersize=\CLASSINFOpaperwidth,\CLASSINFOpaperheight}}}{%
% pdfoutput is defined and not equal to \relax
% check for pdfpageheight existence just in case someone sets pdfoutput
% under non-pdflatex. If exists, set them regardless of value of \pdfoutput.
\@ifundefined{pdfpageheight}{\relax}{\global\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth
\global\pdfpageheight\paperheight}%
% if using \pdfoutput=0 under pdflatex, send dvips papersize special
\ifcase\pdfoutput
\AtBeginDvi{\special{papersize=\CLASSINFOpaperwidth,\CLASSINFOpaperheight}}%
\else
% we are using pdf output, set CLASSINFOpdf flag
\global\CLASSINFOpdftrue
\fi}}
```